# TranslateZ() is ignored for span element

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-animations, css-transforms

The `span` element; the child of the `div` element in the snippet below is behaving unexpectedly. The `span` element's background-color is set to `#0dd` and it's transform properties are set to `scale( 0.5 ) translateZ( 5rem )`. The scale value is respected and shrinks the element to half size; *the translateZ value however is ignored and doesn't change the position of the element*.

The desired result is for the `span` element to be pushed forwards away from it's parent `div`. **Why is translateZ ignored here and how can we translate `span` in the Z direction?**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  perspective: 30rem;
}
section, div, span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
div, span {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
}
div span {
  transform: scale( 0.5 ) translateZ( 5rem );
  background-color: #0dd;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .rotate_y {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY( 360deg );
    }  
  }
</style>

<section class='rotate_y'>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE: Seems to behave properly on IOS. Issue is with desktop Chrome.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity seems to be the culprit but don't know why. It's probably a bug so use transparent background instead:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 30rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rotate_y * {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.rotate_y span {
  transform: scale( 0.5) translateZ( 5rem);
  background-color: rgba(0,221,221,0.5);
}

.rotate_y {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-name: rotateY;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateY {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY( 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY( 360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class='rotate_y'>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Forgot opacity and filter effects usually create strange behavior on 3D transforms ^^. Thx